# Sunspot solr "No field configured for User with name 'C2'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, solr, sunspot

I want to add ordering on my sunspot search. Without ordering search works perfectly.
Here is my search method:

```
def search
    @search = User.search do
      keywords params[:q]
      paginate page: params[:page]
      order_by(:C2, :desc)
    end
    @users = @search.results
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :action => "index" }
    end
  end
```

My User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    text :C1
    text :C2
  end
end
```

So I'm getting

> No field configured for User with name 'C2'

on the order_by line

**Also** I've thought that MAYBE cause of the problem is that C2 is text, not string, so I've done next hack:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    text :C1
    text :C2
    string  :sort_title do
      C2.downcase
    end
  end
end
```

In order to add `order_by (:sort_title, :desc)` in the controller, but for some reason when I reindex this I get:

> NameError: uninitialized constant User::C2

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Share your user model..

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon  plz check carefully, it is there

Comment: I meant the columns of the table..

Comment: users: id, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, created_at, updated_at.

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon I think first error is definitely, because of text type... but what is the cause of second error, I don't even have ideas. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
searchable do
  text :C1
  text :C2
  string :sort_title do |user|
    user.C2.downcase
  end
end
```

Then try to reindex, and it should just go well..

Comment: I wonder, why example code on sunspots github page haven't something like do |post| ? Here you can check: https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot, example next on "Setting Up Objects" section

Comment: Yeah..i wonder too. I just know it because I have used such syntax in my code..and it works.. ;)